# How to work with thickness in ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I want to put the points in a list plot 3D thicker. I'm using the following

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{Xtrain[[i, 1]], Xtrain[[i, 2]], fobs[[i]]}, {i, 1,Length[Xtrain]}], PlotStyle -> Red, FillingStyle -> Thickness[0.5]]
```

I've tried between 0.1 and 0.6 but nothing changes in the points thickness

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `PointSize` as part of the option `PlotStyle`

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[x, {x, 20}, {y, 20}],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you eldo ;)